# How to tell a zip file is password protected from the HTTP response?

Tags: http, zip

When I download a zip file I want to scan the header and body from its HTTP response to see whether the zip file is password protected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because http response codes are function of web servers and (generally speaking) web server do not care about the content it serve. You will get the same response codes if you download image, text file, archive or music file.

Comment: Can I put the content into a zip object or something in java and than try to figure it out?

Comment: @JérômeD'hulst, sure, you can use java to download the object and then test it. But this is other questions, please create new one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278980/how-to-create-a-zip-java-object-from-a-stream-of-bytes